# Imported function in Entity Framework Where clause?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to use a function import in a where clause in entity framework? I have tried the following, but I get a rather cryptic exception to which I cannot find any information about:

```
var q = MyContext.MyEntities.Where("MyContext.MyFunction(it.ID)")
```

(The function is set to return a Boolean)

System.Data.EntitySqlException: 'MyContext.MyFunction' cannot be resolved into a valid type constructor or function., near WHERE predicate, line 6, column 21..

Regards

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying to write is composing a call to a FunctionImport with a query over an EntitySet.

But because FunctionImports are wrappers around StoredProcedures, which are non-composable, this just won't work.

In order for something like this to work, theoretically the function would need to be a wrapper around something composable like a TVF (Table Value Function). But unfortunately TVFs aren't supported in the Entity Framework today.

Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex - back to the drawing board for me!

In my model, each entity refers to another Entity - A refers to B, C & D refer to E, B & E refer to F, etc.

I want to find all entities that ultimately refer (directly and indeirectly) to another entity. I have a sproc that can walk up the references to find if the entity ultimately refers to the one I am looking for. Easy in SQL, hard as heck in EF :(

Do you have any suggestions on what I can do? I could write entity-returning sprocs and just "functionimport" them, but that could easily become unwieldy with lots of sprocs.

Lee

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you want to pass this expression as a string.  You want a proper lambda expression like:

MyContext.MyEntities.Where( entity => MyContext.MyFunction(entity.ID ) );

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - however, as the function isn't returning an entity (just a Boolean) it doesn't exist in the class of MyContext (although I can successfully call it via and EntityClient).

Comment: Well, where does it exist?  Just call it on the right hand side of the => just like you would from anywhere else.

Comment: It doesn't exist as a member of the DataContext object as generated by the Entity framework) as it's not a entity-returning function - it's a boolean-returning.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of the Where extension method[1].  The Where method accepts a function (delegate) which accepts a typed Entity and returns a boolean.  The lambda expression which I supplied (modified to be syntactically correct, since you pointed out that it exists somewhere other than MyContext), will work just fine as a filter for the Where method, and the result will be a collection of entities which "pass" the filter.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx

Comment: But that will result in the where clause being evaluated on the client, won't it?

Comment: My bad, I didn't fully understand your question until now. Alex is absolutely right.